# How to apply mod_rewrite rules to files within directory?

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to apply rewrite conditions in my htaccess file to all pages contained within a specific directory on my website, but not the directory index itself.

Ultimately, I'm trying to remove .php file extension from pages within a specific directory.

**What I currently have now:**

```
https://www.example.com/directory/page-1.php
```

**End result I'm trying to achieve:**

```
https://www.example.com/directory/page-1
```

Additionally, if a user attempts to visit the .php version of the page, it 301 redirects to the new version without the .php file extension.

Example matches:

```
https://www.example.com/directory/page-1.php
https://www.example.com/directory/page-2.php
```

Should not match:

```
https://www.example.com/directory/
```

Here's what I have so far:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \/directory\/[^\s]+$
```

How should the RewriteRule be written?

Comment: What version of Apache are you running on your server?

Comment: Cross-site (follow up) post on ServerFault with an accepted answer: https://serverfault.com/questions/970701/why-is-301-redirect-not-working-after-removing-php-extension-via-htaccess

Answer (score 0):

The expression that might help us to find a RewriteRule can look like:

```
^https?:\/\/(www\.)?example\.com\/directory\/[^\s]+\.php$
```

which would fail our undesired URLs, and pass the desired ones.

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/QpTRc3/1/)

Our RewriteRule might likely look like:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.*\/directory\/)([^\s]+)\.php [NC]
    RewriteRule (.*directory\/)([^\s]+)\.php   $1$2 [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/cp3DIU/1/)

#### RewriteRule Test

You can test your RewriteRules in [htaccess.madewithlove.be](https://htaccess.madewithlove.be/).

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

We might also want to clear our browser cache, every time that we would change our `htaccess` file.

Comment: Ultimately, I'm trying to remove the .php file extension from files within a specific directory. I've edited my post to reflect this. I included your suggestion with a minor change.

Comment: I've been testing with the madewithlove tool as suggested. I'll test on my live server with 302 redirects until I work out any bugs.

Comment: on live server it seems like I'm having URL path problems. It tries to request: http://www.example.com/home/folder/public_html/courses/cool-course

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following rule in htaccess in your `subfolder` create one if it doesn't already exist :

```
 RewriteEngine on
 #rule for /subfolder/htaccess 
#redirect /subfolder/file.php to /file
#The condition bellow prevents infinite loop/Too many redirects  error
RewriteCond %{ENV_REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ /subfolder/$1 [L,R]
#internally map /subfolder/file to /subfolder/file.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)/?$ /subfolder/$1.php [L]
```

If you want to use your root htaccess file instead , then add the following contents:

```
 RewriteEngine on
 #rule for root/.htaccess 
#redirect /subfolder/file.php to /file
#The condition bellow prevents infinite loop/Too many redirects  error
RewriteCond %{ENV_REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^subfolder/(.+)\.php$ /subfolder/$1 [L,R]
#internally map /subfolder/file to /subfolder/file.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^subfolder/(.+)/?$ /subfolder/$1.php [L]
```